# How to handle payments without using in app purchase in ios apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I just submitted an app to Apple and it was rejected because we were requiring users to register a credit card and then use our service by charging some amount from their cards. I don't want to add in app purchases because they deduct the 30% of the amount paid.  I also checked a paypal app in which user enter his credit card payment by paypal app and that is on app store how the things are possible now for me.

Any suggestions, links, or thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: Can you help me, what you have done to solve this problem ?

Comment: At that time we choose to proceed with one of the Financial service provider with their library. My Product owner did a contract with them for providing the support too. You can try finding any library which provide you MasterCard/Visa API with their support for that. Hope this might leads you some help.

Answer (score 5):

Well Apple only allows In app purchases when you are using digital goods.
You can only use for example paypal if you you are selling non digital goods.

If apple reject your app for not using IAP then you only option is to use IAP. Yes apple will take 30% of the amount, but they will supply the backend and transaction systems so it it reasonable that they charge you for that.

Comment: But what my app do is i register user credit card info on a web site then user can purchase offer i provide on my site by using web methods as i call the web methods i will deduct the applicable money from their cards.Actually the transaction is happening on the back end on server but on iphone we send that i need this item and it will be purchased and highlighted on iphone .Still i used to do the IAP.?

Comment: Read the appstore guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: More precise link: [Purchasing and Currencies – Apple AppStore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies).