# Accept credit card payment in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, payment-processing

How can I accept credit card payments from within my iPhone app? The Credit Card Terminal is a good solution but that would mean my app's users have to have their iPhone app installed as well!

How can I do it all from within the app (using a UIWebView if need be)?

I did check out related questions on SO but none really answered the question.

This is not for in-app purchases (we can use StoreKit for that). This is for donations (and the app would be free as the Apple guidelines suggest)

Thanks.

Comment: May be you can donate through PayPal API but I am not sure whether a

Comment: Need to be able to donate to different groups. All of them do not have paypal accounts.

Comment: Sorry but then I am not sure if you have any other option.

Comment: Here are some popular payment processors: [http://www.ogone.com/](http://www.ogone.com/) [http://www.realexpayments.com/](http://www.realexpayments.com/) [http://www.sagepay.com/](http://www.sagepay.com/) [http://www.worldpay.com/](http://www.worldpay.com/) [http://paypal.com/](http://paypal.com/) [http://www.zooz.com/](http://www.zooz.com/) [https://stripe.com/](https://stripe.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can donate through PayPal API but I am not sure whether Apple will approve it.

PayPal API for iOS:

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep

Refer to this link before you start:

[PayPal API for iOS - allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148370/paypal-api-for-ios-allowed)

I think there is no other option. UIWebView can open a site in your application which accepts credit card payments but I am not sure how good and appealing it would be to a user.

Hope this helps you

**EDIT:**

If you use anything apart from PayPal and In App Purchase, then I fear that your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: Parth, not sure if the app would be rejected if it is PCI compliant. There is nothing in the guidelines saying you cannot accept payment other than the 2 means mentioned. As I said, I cannot use paypal coz all orgs I am targeting do not have a paypal account. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @lostInTransit: You can refer to answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467887/how-to-handle-payments-without-using-in-app-purchase-in-ios-apps.

Comment: Thanks but probably they were rejected due to PCI incompliance? I do not want to store the user's CC info in my app. I can send them out to an API via an HTTPs call.

Comment: I understand that but I don't think there is any other way you can do this.

Comment: @lostInTransit http://bypasslane.com/ see app. shown here, they have option to add card and process already present cards.