# creating a credit card payment gateway inside an app

Tags: iphone, credit-card

I am developing an app using Titanium for both iPhone and Android. I want to allow users to input their credit card details and then whenever they confirm a payment I just send the data to a credit card processing company. The payment is for pizza, not for App Content, so I assume Apple doesn't have a problem with this. Should I use a webview for the credit card processing, or how do you suggest implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your own processor, you can use [card.io](https://www.card.io/) or [Jumio](https://pay.jumio.com/) to capture the credit card digits so the user doesn't have to type them in.  Then just pass the credit card number, CVV and expiration date to your API to process the payment.  Doing this in a webview or native shouldn't make a difference.

There is a PayPal API for mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469274/accept-credit-card-payment-in-iphone-app) on SO.  It still launches a webview though.